# How to make relative links work in a .rmd file?

Tags: hyperlink, r-markdown

I am finishing an online tutorial created by Jeniffer Bryan. There is a section about relative links in Git markdown files. I tried and looked at examples, but it never works in my .rmd file.

I tried to use branch names and the whole path, but the result is always "/rmd_output/1/master/ds.md not found" and "No image at path plot.jpg."

```
[a link](master/ds.md)
[a link](hwsf/ds.md)
![image1](plot.jpg)
```

When you click on "a link," you should be directed to another page, namely "ds.md." I am asking this question, because I've ensured that the documents ds.md and plot.jpg are in the desired directory.

Comment: when you say "in git", are you meaning in markdown?  like in an .md file?

Comment: @DanFarrell Yes! It's a Rmarkdown file.

Comment: okay, thanks.  I am not seeing any reference of git or github here so I'm going to take the liberty of changing your question's tags so the right people can find it.  I know you probably don't have rep to edit your own post so if you feel like I did something I shouldn't have let me know.  With the `rmarkdown` tag I think the relevant folks will be able to find your question